# How do I get XML path by its value?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to get the xml path opf the xml file by providing the value of an xml child element as the input.

For example:

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <document-inquiry xmlns="http://ops.epo.org">
    <publication-reference data-format="docdb" xmlns="http://www.epo.org/exchange">
      <document-id>
        <country>EP</country>
        <doc-number>1000</doc-number>
        <kind>A1</kind>
      </document-id>
    </publication-reference>    
  </document-inquiry>
```

For the above XML file. I need to get the XML path by using the value "1000".
If my input is value of the element "1000"
Output i need is :

```
 <document-id>
        <country>EP</country>
        <doc-number>1000</doc-number>
        <kind>A1</kind>
  </document-id>
```

I need to achieve this using c# code. Can anyone please help me out on this...

Comment: Please don't shout, I'm feeling a bit delicate this morning.

Comment: Edited the title to not be so loud.

Comment: So you don't need to get the path as output - you need the ancestor element. Maybe change the question title, or modify the question if you do want the path.

Comment: Edited the title to remove the grocer's apostrophe, 'cos I'm a pedant like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx) extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        ns.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.epo.org/exchange");
        var elem = XDocument.Load("test.xml")
            .XPathSelectElement("//ns:document-id[ns:doc-number='1000']", ns);
        if (elem != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You could use [XPathSelectElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356942.aspx) if you want to select multiple nodes that correspond to this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element that you want with a linq query.

```
var number = "1000";
var xml = XDocument.Parse( xml_string );
XNamespace ns = "http://www.epo.org/exchange";

var result = (from data in xml.Descendants(ns + "document-id")
           where data.Element(ns + "doc-number").Value == number
           select data).FirstOrDefault();
```

`.FirstOrDefault()` returns the first matching element or null. You could instead use `.List()` to get a list containing all matching elements.